# Stopclock with a For Loop continues past limit and counter seems broken

Tags: vb.net

Currently attempting a very simple private project of making a stopclock display a countdown after the user hits "start". Ideally, the clock is meant to count down to zero a number of times equal to TotalLap. It is also supposed to remove an amount of time (1 minute x current lap) from the timer before it starts again.

I have tried a While loop and now a For loop. In both cases what I call "the counter", which is labeled "CurrentLap" is going to the max value plus 1 (I added a label to show me the CurrentLap value and it's always 1 higher than the TotalLap after the first run, skipping all the other laps).

So my issues follow:
1) I have yet to find a good place to put the stop command for my timer
2) CurrentLap goes from 0 straight to 4 (according to my label for it)

Below I will include my code, which will include the commented-out previous attempts. Please keep in mind I'm relatively inexperienced with programming and know very little of the terminology (learning new skills!). Thanks in advance.

Edit: As an aside, Time is currently set to .25 for faster testing, it is normally an integer value.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim CurrentLap As Integer = 0
Dim TotalLap As Integer = 4
Dim Time As Decimal = 0.25
'Dim TimeReduction As Decimal = 0.25
'Dim StartTime As Decimal = (Time - TimeReduction)

Private TargetDT As DateTime

Private CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Time)


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    tmrCountdown.Interval = 1000
    TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
    tmrCountdown.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

    If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
        lblTime.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
    Else
        lblTime.Text = "00:00"
        tmrCountdown.Dispose()
        CurrentLap = CurrentLap + 1


        For CurrentLap = 0 To TotalLap Step 1
            tmrCountdown.Start()
            TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)

            If CurrentLap = TotalLap Then Exit For


        Next CurrentLap


        'While CurrentLap < TotalLap
        'tmrCountdown.Start()
        'TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
        'CurrentLap = CurrentLap + 1
        'End While

        'If CurrentLap < TotalLap Then
        'CurrentLap = CurrentLap + 1
        'TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
        'tmrCountdown.Start()

        'Else
        'tmrCountdown.Stop()
        'MsgBox("Race Over")
        'End If

    End If
    lblCurrentLap.Text = CurrentLap.ToString("")


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Don't use a loop; just stop or restart the timer __once__, increment `CurrentLap`, and exit the 'tick' event handler. It will come around upon the next tick.

Comment: Oh, and __don't__ `Dispose` your timer if you don't know what that means.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Thank you. Removing the dispose and loop has enabled the CurrentLap to increment correctly. I now only start the timer in the button click event and once in the tick event (or did you mean only once, period?). 

However, I am now seeing the clock stay at "00:00", when I need it to restart a certain number of times limited by total lap. Would a loop not be required to maintain that restriction?

Comment: Compare it to the physical world. You have a stopwatch in your hand; will it do you much good pressing the start button 4 times in quick succession without waiting for time to elapse? That's what your loop was doing. And as for any remaining bugs, that should now just be a matter of debugging.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Thank you. I removed the loop and got it working! I now have a separate issue which I will list as a separate question if I can't fix it on my own. Thank you for your help!